# Executed subqueries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am running the below query

```sql
(
  select Game.GameID, Game.season, GamePlaysPlayers.playerID
  from (select Game.GameID, Game.season, GamePlaysPlayers.playerID
        from Game 
        inner join GamePlaysPlayers on Game.GameID = GamePlaysPlayers.GameID 
        where Game.season = '20082009'
       )
  inner join (
    select Game.GameID, Game.season, GamePlaysPlayers.playerID 
    from Game 
    inner join GamePlaysPlayers on Game.GameID = GamePlaysPlayers.GameID 
    where Game.season = '20182019'
  ) on Game.GameID = GamePlaysPlayers.GameID
);
```

And I got the error "Every derived table must have its own alias".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear.
If you refer to MySQL documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html, a name for every derived table is mandatory so you must include a `AS` clause to both subqueries.
I guess that the names would be "Game" for the first subquery and "GamePlaysPlayers" for the second one.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I tried as u suggested and here is my below code.             `select * from 
(
select Game.GameID, Game.season, GamePlaysPlayers.playerID from Game  inner join GamePlaysPlayers on Game.GameID = GamePlaysPlayers.GameID where Game.season = '20082009' ) as T 
inner join 
(
select Game.GameID, Game.season, GamePlaysPlayers.playerID from Game inner join GamePlaysPlayers on Game.GameID = GamePlaysPlayers.GameID where Game.season = '20182019') as S 
on T.playerID = S.playerID;`    But I didn’t get any results for the above query.

Comment: So the error you referred to in your initial question is fixed. Whether the results satisfy your needs or not is a different topic. From what I understand of your database, you want to extract players who participated to both 2008-2009 and 2018-2019 seasons. Do you really think the result should be different?

Comment: Yes, You are right! I need to extract the players who played games in the 2008/2009 season also played games in the 2018/2019 season